# Build a tabbar view controller from scratch

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uitabbarcontroller, orientation

Apple's tab bar controller has a lot of limitations. One important limitation is that you can't modify the tab bar in a rejection safe mode. My tab bar has a simple sliding movements and it's multi row.
For those reasons I decided to build a TBVC from the beginning; everything seems to work correctly, but I'm really messing around with rotation. Every time that I change orientation  main view frames are changed.

Here is my hierarchy from top to the container view:
-MainView--contains-->TabBarView+containerView
The containerView is the view used to contain views loaded from the other controllers.
Here is the -loadView method of my CustomTabBaViewController

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *theView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    theView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    theView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    containerOfControllersView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:theView.bounds];
    containerOfControllersView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    containerOfControllersView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [theView addSubview:containerOfControllersView];

    ideoloTabBar=[[IdeoloTabBar alloc]initWithNumberOfControllers:[controllers count]];
    [theView addSubview:ideoloTabBar];
    self.view=theView;
    [theView release];
    
}
```

When I set a new view from another controller I use this method:

```
-(void)setCurrentViewWithView:(UIView*)theView{
    if ([[self.containerOfControllersView subviews] count]>0) {
        UIView *tagView=[self.containerOfControllersView viewWithTag:555];
        tagView.tag=0;
        [tagView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    theView.tag=555;
    theView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    theView.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
    [self.containerOfControllersView addSubview:theView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:ideoloTabBar];
}
```

As you can see the views from other view controllers are applied using the applicationFrame.

When I rotate the device happens something wrong, the mainview not only is resized according to the new orientation but also moved by 20px (status bar size) to the botton,  thus leaving a gap between the status bar and the container view. Since I gave the mainview the screen bounds I can't understand with it should be moved.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying a different approach so I've modified the loadView like that:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    containerOfControllersView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    containerOfControllersView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    containerOfControllersView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:containerOfControllersView];
    ideoloTabBar=[[IdeoloTabBar alloc]initWithNumberOfControllers:[controllers count]];
    [self.view addSubview:ideoloTabBar];
}
```

And in the setCurrentViewWithView:(UIView*)theView I've modified the line with

```
theView.frame=self.view.bounds;
```

instead of using the applicationFrame.

#### NOW:

On iPhone when I try to load a modalView it cuts about 40px at the bottom
On iPad when I try to load a modalView it lefts 20px at the bottom, because 20px are under the status bar but wantsFullScreen is NO.

#### UPDATE 2

It seems that the presentModalViewController should be called from the root view controller. I will create a protocol and an abstract UIViewController subclass to implement it an load it correctly.

Any suggestion? work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I'm using my custom TabBarViewController with disappearing tabbar and it seems to work properly both on iPad and iPhone.
The main problem that I had was due to an incorrect assignment to the content view frame and probably to a wrong assumption that modalVC were loaded from the current view controller.
First point: the content view should use the bounds of the main view, here is a part of the loadView method of the Root View Controller:

```
[super loadView];
containerOfControllersView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Second:before add as a subview a view of a view controller remark to it that its frame should have the same bounds of its new parent view.

```
    theView.frame =self.view.bounds;
```

Third: modal view controllers should be loaded from the root view controller or the will never have correct size. That's why I've implemented a base abstract class for each view controllers that inherit a protocol that manage the presetation and dismissing of modal viewcontrollers.
Hope this helps someone else.
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the approach of creating an entirely custom TabBarController from scratch.  I like to put a custom view on top of a real TabBar as a subview, and then pass all the button presses to the real TabBarController.  This way you don't have to code a window manager yourself.

```
- (void)tabButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (button.tag == HomeButton)
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

    // etc.
}
```

This should also be rejection safe.

Comment: Thanks hundreth..I see you point, but most of the times a customer will require something different from the UITabBar, this means that you must substitute it with a view and start everything from scratch. In second instance, if you try to animate or hide the tabbar the main view of the tabbarviewcontroller will be completely screw up when you rotate, call modals, navigate etc and it's very hard to fix those behaviours.

Comment: Not if you do this intelligently.  A subview on a TabBar view with the proper auto-resizing masks should always behave properly.  It is much easier to fix display problems with a subview than it is to build an entire window manager from scratch.  Just my opinion.

Comment: Sorry.. I've should explained it better. One time I've tried to add a appear/disappear animation to the UITabBar of a UITabBarController. I made it but I had a lot of problems with the resizing behaviour of the  content view of UITabBarController and I was only able to fix that just changing some private properties (not good for AppStore publication). Your approach is better and faster but  not suitable in my case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed here: [Application frame leaves blank line at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816859/application-frame-leaves-blank-line-at-the-top)

But, you could also specify your frame by subtracting 20 from `y`:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
theView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 20, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
```

Comment: Thx Daniel, seems to be same issue, but is not.